# more efficiency way for performance in React Component Mounting

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've made many `Modals` in React.

I found 2 ways of making `Modal`.

The first one is like this

```
class Modal extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount(){ console.log('DidMount') };
  componentDidUpdate(){ console.log('DidUpdate') };
  componentWillUnmount(){ console.log('WillUnmount') };

  render(){
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="overlay" />
        <div className="Modal>
          This is Modal.
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}


class App extends React.Component { 
  state = {
    isModalOpen: false
  }

  toggleModal = () => this.setState({ isModalOpen: !this.state.isModalOpen })  
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.toggleModal}>Toggle</button>
        { this.state.isModalOpen ? <Modal /> : null }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

This one repeats `componentDidMount()`&`componentWillUnmount()` when the state changed.

Let's see the other one.

```
class Modal extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount(){ console.log('DidMount') };
  componentDidUpdate(){ console.log('DidUpdate') };
  componentWillUnmount(){ console.log('WillUnmount') };

  render(){
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        { props.isOpen ? <div className="overlay" /> : null }
        { props.isOpen ? <div className="Modal">This is Modal</div> : null }
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }

}
class App extends React.Component { 
  state = {
    isModalOpen: false
  }

  toggleModal = () => this.setState({ isModalOpen: !this.state.isModalOpen })  

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.toggleModal}>Toggle</button>
        <Modal isOpen={this.state.isModalOpen} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

This one would not call `componentWillUnmount()`.

It would call `componentDidUpdate()` when the state changed.

I wonder which one is a better way for the performance or something else.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm a little confused on what your question is. They both do the same thing

Comment: @AdrianLineweaver oh, maybe I need to edit my question because my real code is `Class Component`

Answer (score 0):

React.Fragment is a little bit fast and uses less memory because it doesn't need to create an extra DOM node.

With that being said unless your application is big and complex I wouldn't worry about it. I'm not exactly sure what wrapping the modal div in a React.Fragment is achieving.

Answer (score 0):

You question is a bit confusing but I will attempt to clarify a few things.

Regarding your comment: This one would not call `componentWillUnmount()`. It will not call the the `cWU()` method because you are always rendering it by using this `<Modal isOpen={this.state.isModalOpen} />` within your render. Now wether it appears or not based on your `isOpen` prop it's a different issue. On the other hand if you had something like `{isThisPropertyTrue ? <Modal isOpen={this.state.isModalOpen} /> : null}`, and your `isThisPropertyTrue` was toggling from true to false, then you would notice the `console.log` in your unmount hook.
This method `{ this.state.isModalOpen ? <Modal /> : null }` has a better performance since the modal is render upon request.